# SQL between in case in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, between

I try to write a query that return data where Date_column between param result and param -12 months when parameter is not null or where Date_column is not null where param is null. Can You help me? 
I tried many variants but always have some errors.

```
declare @my_date DateTime
select * from MyTable
where 
case when @my_date is null 
           then Date_column is not null
           else Date_column between @my_date and DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @my_date)
           end
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes, You have right. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you write you condition like below without `case` expression

```
  where (Date_column is not null and  @my_date is null ) or 
     (Date_column between  DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @my_date) and @my_date)
```

Comment: Yes, so simply. THX.